# How to solve Php Error Cannot instantiate abstract class sfDoctrineRecord on Symfony 1.5.9?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a problem when I want to use the command on terminal (linux)

```
php symfony doctrine:build --all --and-load
```

The terminal displays the next message:

```
>> doctrine  generating sql for models
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class sfDoctrineRecord in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php:301
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php(256): Doctrine_Table->initDefinition()
#1 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php(1126): Doctrine_Table->__construct('sfDoctrineRecor...', Object(Doctrine_Connection_Pgsql), true)
#2 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php(368): Doctrine_Connection->getTable('sfDoctrineRecor...')
#3 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php(425): Doctrine_Relation_Parser->guessColumns(Array, Object(CotizacionTable))
#4 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/ in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php on line 301

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class sfDoctrineRecord in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php:301
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php(256): Doctrine_Table->initDefinition()
#1 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php(1126): Doctrine_Table->__construct('sfDoctrineRecor...', Object(Doctrine_Connection_Pgsql), true)
#2 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php(368): Doctrine_Connection->getTable('sfDoctrineRecor...')
#3 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Relation/Parser.php(425): Doctrine_Relation_Parser->guessColumns(Array, Object(CotizacionTable))
#4 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/ in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Table.php on line 301
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function evictAll() on null in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php:1239
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php(1268): Doctrine_Connection->clear()
#1 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Manager.php(580): Doctrine_Connection->close()
#2 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineDatabase.class.php(165): Doctrine_Manager->closeConnection(Object(Doctrine_Connection_Pgsql))
#3 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/database/sfDatabaseManager.class.php(134): sfDoctrineDatabase->shutdown()
#4 [internal function]: sfDatabaseManager->shutdown()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function evictAll() on null in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php:1239
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php(1268): Doctrine_Connection->clear()
#1 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Manager.php(580): Doctrine_Connection->close()
#2 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/database/sfDoctrineDatabase.class.php(165): Doctrine_Manager->closeConnection(Object(Doctrine_Connection_Pgsql))
#3 /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/database/sfDatabaseManager.class.php(134): sfDoctrineDatabase->shutdown()
#4 [internal function]: sfDatabaseManager->shutdown()
#5 {main}
  thrown in /home/mario/Proyecto/TakeoffBI/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php on line 1239
```

I dont know what to do, I tried to clean the symfony cache and restart postgresql

There are my Schemas.yml

```
    actAs: 
  Signable:  
    created:
      name: created_by
      type: integer
      onUpdate: CASCADE
      onDelete: SET NULL
      options:
         notnull: true
         default: 1
    updated:
      name: updated_by
      type: integer

Proyecto:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      nombre:           { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      cliente_id:       { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      fecha_inicio:     { type: date,        notnull: true }
      fecha_final:      { type: date,        notnull: false}
      estado:           { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      responsable_id:   { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      descripcion:      { type: string,      notnull: true }
      tipo_solucion_id: { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      etapa_id:         { type: integer,     notnull: true }  
    relations:
      TipoSolucion: { local: tipo_solucion_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Proyectos }
      Cliente:      { local: cliente_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Proyectos }
      Etapa:        { local: etapa_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Proyectos }
      sfGuardUser:  { local: responsable_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Proyectos} 

TipoSolucion:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      nombre: { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }

Cliente:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      nombre:         { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      telefono:       { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      nit:            { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      direccion:      { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    relations:
      Proyecto:       { onDelete: CASCADE, local: id, foreign: cliente_id, foreignAlias: Clientes }

Cotizacion:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      numero:         { type: integer, notnull: true }
      proyecto_id:    { type: integer, notnull: true }
      fecha:          { type: date,    notnull: true }
      venta_total:    { type: integer, notnull: true }
      costo_total:    { type: integer, notnull: true }
      garantia:       { type: integer, notnull: true }
      tiempo_entrega: { type: date, notnull: true }
    relations:
      Proyecto:       { onDelete: CASCADE, local: proyecto_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Cotizaciones }
      Producto:       { local: id, foreign: cotizacion_id, foreignAlias: Cotizaciones }

Contacto:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      nombre:         { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      apellido:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      telefono:       { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      celular:        { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      cliente_id:     { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      funcion:        { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    relations:
      Cliente:        { onDelete: CASCADE, local: cliente_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Contactos}

Etapa:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      descripcion:    { type: string(255), notnull: false }
      responsable_id: { type: integer,     notnull: false }
      nombre:         { type: string(255), notnull: true }
    relations:
      Proyecto:       { local: id, foreign: etapa_id, foreignAlias: Etapas}

Producto:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      descripcion:    { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      cantidad:       { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      costo:          { type: integer,     notnull: true }
      nombre:         { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      marca:          { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      modelo:         { type: string(255), notnull: true }
      cotizacion_id:   { type: integer,     notnull: false } 
    relations:
      Cotizacion:       { local: cotizacion_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Productos}

Financiamiento:
    actAs: [Timestampable,Signable]
    columns:
      monto:              { type: integer, notnull: true }
      inversionista:      { type: string,  notnull: true }
      tasa_interes:       { type: integer, notnull: true }
      fecha_inicio:       { type: date,    notnull: true}
      proyecto_id:        { type: integer, notnull: true}
    relations:
      Proyecto:       { local: proyecto_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: Financiamientos}
```

and my sfDoctrineGuard Schema.yml

```
   sfGuardGroup:
      actAs: 
            Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        name:
          type: string(255)
          unique: true
        description: string(1000)
      relations:
        Users:
          class: sfGuardUser
          refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
          local: group_id
          foreign: user_id
          foreignAlias: Groups
        Permissions:
          class: sfGuardPermission
          local: group_id
          foreign: permission_id
          refClass: sfGuardGroupPermission
          foreignAlias: Groups

    sfGuardPermission:
      actAs:
            Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        name:
          type: string(255)
          unique: true
        description: string(1000)

    sfGuardGroupPermission:
      options:
        symfony:
          form:   false
          filter: false
      actAs:
            Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        group_id:
          type: integer
          primary: true
        permission_id:
          type: integer
          primary: true
      relations:
        Group:
          class: sfGuardGroup
          local: group_id
          onDelete: CASCADE
        Permission:
          class: sfGuardPermission
          local: permission_id
          onDelete: CASCADE

    sfGuardUser:
      actAs:
            Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        first_name: string(255)
        last_name: string(255)
        direccion: string(255)
        ci: integer
        telefono: integer
        email_address:
          type: string(255)
          notnull: false
          unique: true
        username:
          type: string(128)
          notnull: true
          unique: true
        algorithm:
          type: string(128)
          default: sha1
          notnull: true
        salt: string(128)
        password: string(128)
        is_active:
          type: boolean
          default: 1
        is_super_admin:
          type: boolean
          default: false
        last_login:
          type: timestamp
      indexes:
        is_active_idx:
          fields: [is_active]
      relations:
        Groups:
          class: sfGuardGroup
          local: user_id
          foreign: group_id
          refClass: sfGuardUserGroup
          foreignAlias: Users
        Permissions:
          class: sfGuardPermission
          local: user_id
          foreign: permission_id
          refClass: sfGuardUserPermission
          foreignAlias: Users
        Proyecto:
          class: Proyecto
          local: id
          foreign: responsable_id
          foreignAlias: Users

    sfGuardUserPermission:
      options:
        symfony:
          form:   false
          filter: false
      actAs:
          Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        user_id:
          type: integer
          primary: true
        permission_id:
          type: integer
          primary: true
      relations:
        User:
          class: sfGuardUser
          local: user_id
          onDelete: CASCADE
        Permission:
          class: sfGuardPermission
          local: permission_id
          onDelete: CASCADE

    sfGuardUserGroup:
      options:
        symfony:
          form:   false
          filter: false
      actAs:
          Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        user_id:
          type: integer
          primary: true
        group_id:
          type: integer
          primary: true
      relations:
        User:
          class: sfGuardUser
          local: user_id
          onDelete: CASCADE
        Group:
          class: sfGuardGroup
          local: group_id
          onDelete: CASCADE

    sfGuardRememberKey:
      options:
        symfony:
          form:   false
          filter: false
      actAs:
          Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        user_id: integer
        remember_key: string(32)
        ip_address: string(50)
      relations:
        User:
          class: sfGuardUser
          local: user_id
          foreignAlias: RememberKeys
          foreignType: one
          onDelete: CASCADE

    sfGuardForgotPassword:
      options:
        symfony:
          form:   false
          filter: false
      actAs:
          Timestampable: ~
      columns:
        user_id:
          type: integer
          notnull: true
        unique_key: string(255)
        expires_at:
          type: timestamp
          notnull: true
      relations:
        User:
          class: sfGuardUser
          local: user_id
          type: one
          foreignType: one
          foreignAlias: ForgotPassword
          onDelete: CASCADE
```

I have Fixtures too, I dont know what to do, thank you

Comment: I think your schemas.yml is missing line or two at the very top.  This might be causing to not be parsed correct and causing your error.